# Kubernetes cluster x509: Certifcate issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, kubernetes, x509, kops

I set up **[Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes)** cluster on **aws** using **[kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)** using **[this tutorial](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md)** on official kubernetes github branch.

The cluster set up successfully on AWS, but when I try to run

```
kubectl get nodes
```

or

```
kops validate cluster
```

it says

```
[user@ip-70-0-0-7 ~]$ kubectl cluster-info
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for *.secure.hosting prod.com, not api.subdomain.mydomain.com
```

This is definitely problem with my **x509 certificates**. Just need a gentle push to right direction. Thank you for your precious time and help!

`NOTE: I am running these commands from outside the cluster from a machine from where I did set up of cluster.`

Comment: Which OS are you using? There is an installation dependency regarding certificates on at least CENTOS.

Comment: It's amazon ami

Comment: Hi Arjun, Did you resolve this? If so, what method you finally followed.

Comment: @Shruti The one mentioned in the answer by Daniel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for *.secure.hosting prod.com, not api.subdomain.mydomain.com

I can't tell if those names you listed are examples, or the actual values that `kubectl` is giving you, but I'll use them as you've written just to keep things simple

If the kubernetes cluster you installed is really accessible via `api.secure.hostingprod.com`, then updating your `$HOME/.kube/config` to say `https://api.secure.hostingprod.com` where it currently says `https://api.subdomain.mydomain.com` should get things back in order.

Alternatively, if `api.secure.hosting prod.com` is not an actual domain you can use (for example, if your certificate really does have a space in the hostname), then you have a couple of options.

The cheapest, but least correct, might be to just tell `kubectl` "I know what I'm doing, don't check the cert" by setting the `insecure-skip-tls-verify` option under the `cluster` entry in the `$HOME/.kube/config` file:

```
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
```

The more bothersome, but also most correct, would be to re-issue the certificate for the API server using the actual hostname (apparently `api.subdomain.mydomain.com`). If you know how, extra-super-best is to also add "Subject Alternate Names" (abbreviated as "SAN") to the certificate, so that in-cluster members can refer to it as `https://kubernetes` and/or `https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`, along with the `Service` IP address assigned to the `kubernetes` `Service` in the `default` namespace. It's extremely likely that your current certificate has those values, which `openssl x509 -in /path/to/your.crt -noout -text` will show you what they currently are. If you need help with the openssl bits, CoreOS Kubernetes has [a shell script](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/blob/v0.8.6/lib/init-ssl) they use, which might work as written or if nothing else provide very concrete guidance.

I do recognize that's a lot of words, and also a lot of work, but certificates are super important so getting them as correct as possible will really save everyone heartache down the line.